# How to turn Python Turtle to .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe, turtle-graphics

How do I turn my python turtle script to .exe? I tried py2exe and it did execute my script but the cmd showed up for like 1 milisecond. I think it is because I am using turtle graphics instead of normal python script. Is there any way to turn my turtle program into .exe?

Comment: In order to get to the error message you should start the command line and execute your program from there. This will avoid the cmd screen being closed when the error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `done()` or `exitonclick()` for the last command