# How to run a python game, without going into the code via IDE

Tags: python, python-turtle

i am learning python, i have created a pong game. i would like to run the game without going into Thonny python IDE and clicking run, maybe create a desktop icon? how would i go about doing this?
thanks for your help.

Comment: Just try to convert your code as python executable, this way you wont be able to run, its just like opening any application. Just checkout the below link how to do .py --> .exe.

`[link](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)`

Comment: You can start your script from the command line. Look at the second chapter of the tuorial: [Using the Python Interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#using-the-python-interpreter). Other options depend on the operating system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn Python Turtle to .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50370233/how-to-turn-python-turtle-to-exe)